# How to add farm solution without using Visual Studio, PowerShell or Stsadm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepointadmin, farm-solution

I have a farm solution wsp which I want to add and deploy on a client's SharePoint farm.

Now I don't have remote access to this SharePoint machine but do have full admin rights to its central admin and related site collection, and can open the central admin and all sites through my machine.

Now as per my knowledge a farm solution is added to the SharePoint farm and not to the site collection, but I could not find any screen in central admin from which I can add my solution.

This is the case with both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 servers.

What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it sounds like you need to add and deploy a farm solution only using central admin?  I don't think that is possible.  If you look step one from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544500%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> **Adding**: A solution package is added by a farm administrator to the farm's solution store, which is in the farm's configuration database. This is done either with the SharePoint Management Shell (or with the object model). ***It cannot be done in Central Administration.***

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this through web interface.
If you have full admin rights - you can use Remote PowerShell. But this require some setup on server. You can read this article about this: http://blog.incworx.com/blog/nik-brendlers-blog/administer-your-sharepoint-farm-remotely-with-powershell